# Watchdog does not work after update from 18.04 server to 20.04 server

Tags: server, watchdog

After update from 18.04 server to 20.04 server watchdog does not work any more.
Output after `/etc/init.d/watchdog status` always contains the following line:

```
Mai 18 11:52:08 idefix watchdog[1523]: cannot set scheduler (errno = 1 = 'Operation not permitted')
```

The commands

```
apt-get --purge remove watchdog
```

and

```
apt-get install watchdog
```

did not help!
The problem did not occur on a server with identical hardware with a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.

How to solve this?

Comment: "The problem did not occur on a server with identical hardware with a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04." sure but what does that have to do with it? "Operation not permitted" is a PERMISSION error. So you need to be thinking about a user having permissions to the scheduler = cpu   Your issue will be systemd related too. How about adding `ControlGroup=cpu:/`  to the `[Service]` section of the systemd watchdog service?

Comment: Sorry, but this did not work ...